# Showing next container once previous section has been completed

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I want to only display the next container once the previous container's child has been selected.

```
<section class="section-blue" id="question1">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="question-heading">Q1: WHO ARE YOU MOST LIKE?</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question2"><img src="../images/1.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">THOMAS EDISON</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question2"><img src="../images/2.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">ALBERT EINSTEIN</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question2"><img src="../images/3.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">NELSON MANDELA</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="section-red" id="question2">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="question-heading">Q2: WHAT’S YOUR PREFERENCE?</h1>
        <div class="row center-block">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question3"><img src="../images/4.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">CHESS</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question3"><img src="../images/5.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">FOOTY</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a href="#question3"><img src="../images/6.png" class="img-rounded image-sizes" alt="Cinque Terre">
                    <br>
                    <p style="color: white;">LEGO</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So question #1 should be displayed when you first open the webpage, then once you have clicked one of the pictures, it takes you to question #2. question #2 would be hidden until question #1's child has been clicked.

[Have a look at my codepen here](https://codepen.io/erayner/pen/vyMzRZ)

A good example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here
https://www.randstad.co.uk/ugc/found/tech-entrepreneur-match/

Comment: Please note that this isn't a forum. Take the [tour] and see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/SwishWez/pen/GNLXex) which does what you'd like.

It works as follows:

- Hide all sections at first with CSS
- Number the sections based on their order in the dom
- Show the first section
- Bind a handler for each answer click to take the index of the parent section and show the next section based on that (as well as highlighting)

I added a couple of CSS classes (section, section.highlight and answer) but here's the essence:

```
$(() => {
  init();
});

function init() {
  numberSections();
  bindAnswerClick();
  showSection(0);
}

function numberSections() {
  $(".section").each((index, elem) => {
    $(elem).data("index", index);
    $(elem).attr("data-index", index);
  });
}

function bindAnswerClick() {
  $(".answer").on("click", (e) => {
    selectAnswer($(e.currentTarget));
  });
}

function selectAnswer($answer) {
  let $section = $answer.closest(".section");
  let nextIndex = parseInt($section.data("index")) + 1;

  $section.find(".answer").removeClass("highlight");
  $answer.addClass("highlight");

  showSection(nextIndex);
}

function showSection(index) {
  $(".section[data-index='" + index + "']").show();
}
```